# Best practices or PEP conventions for collecting and centralizing custom types for type hinting

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a number of custom types I've created for type hinting.  For example

```
from typing import Dict
import pandas as pd

InputData = Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]
```

These custom types will be used to annotate variables in different sub-packages of my project.  To avoid having to retype these many times, it seems prudent to collect these in some file or package that can be imported when needed.

Are there conventions or PEP standards on how to do this?  I haven't seen examples of collecting type defs in a dedicated package, but it seems to make sense.

Comment: I haven't seen any guidelines on this. I will say this, however: I used to do this quite a bit, and still do sometimes, but have recently been trying to do it less. It's often the case that the further away the type-hint definition is from the thing it's annotating, the less readable the function/class/variable definition becomes, in my opinion.